# Write an instance method advance the time by those minutes

Tags: swift, class, methods, time, instance

I am new to swift and I am teaching myself. I know it's customary to have sample code but I'm extremely lost. I'm trying to write an instance method `advance` that will be placed inside the `ClockTime` class. The method accepts a number of minutes as its parameter and moves your object forward in time by that amount of minutes. The minutes passed could be any non-negative number, even a large number such as 500 or 1000000. If necessary, your object might wrap into the next hour or day, or it might wrap from the morning ("AM") to the evening ("PM") or vice versa.

Note: A `ClockTime` object doesn't care about what day it is; if you advance by 1 minute from 11:59 PM, it becomes 12:00 AM.

For example, the following calls would produce the following results:

```
ClockTime time = new ClockTime(6, 27, "PM");

time.advance(1);       //  6:28 PM

time.advance(30);      //  6:58 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
struct ClockTime {
    var hour: Int {
        return components.hour!
    }
    var minute: Int {
        return components.minute!
    }

    private var internalTime = Date()
    private var components: DateComponents {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: internalTime)
    }

    mutating func advance(by minutes: TimeInterval) {
        internalTime.addTimeInterval(minutes * 60)
    }
}
```

Comment: so how would input and output interact with that method? i plan on putting a text box for receiving the amount of minutes. So would a label be used to display what the new time is?

Comment: The UI is outside the scope of this question. If you have a question about displaying the new time in the UI, please open a new question. I'm not sure what you're referring to as input and output.

Comment: how do i call this method if a playground?

Comment: Paste the above code into a playground, create an instance ( var myTime = ClockTime() ), and then call the method ( myTime.advance(by: 10) ).